# How to scroll contents in label?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to scroll contents in a label. I'm a begginer. Please help me.
I did it like below.But it doesn't working. I found this from the internet. But it doesn't working. I take some data from a .txt file and i need to display in a lable. The lable is not enough to display them all. So I need to scroll the contents in the label.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window=tk.Tk()

im = Image.open("landscape2.png")
tkimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)

tab5 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab5, text='History')

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

his_lbl = tk.Label(tab5, image=tkimage)
his_lbl.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

his_frame = tk.Frame(tab5, bg='#80c1ff',bd=5)
his_frame.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.1, relheight=0.1, relwidth=0.50, 
anchor= 'n')

button = tk.Button(his_frame, bg = 'white', command = lambda: 
get_weather(his_entry.get()))
button.place(relx = 0.7, relheight = 1, relwidth  = 0.3)

his_entry = tk.Entry(his_frame, font =('Courier', 18))
his_entry.place(relheight = 1, relwidth = 0.65)

canvas = Canvas(tab5, bg="white")
canvas.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.25, relheight = 0.6, relwidth = 0.50, 
anchor='n')


lst = []
y = 0

label = Label(canvas,anchor='w', font=("Courier", 20), 
compound=RIGHT,bg='white',bd=4, justify="left")
label.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
canvas.create_window(0, y, window=label, anchor=NW)

y += 60

scrollbar = Scrollbar(canvas, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=NE)
canvas.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, scrollregion=(0, 0, 0, y))

def get_weather(history):
    file=open((history+".txt"),("r"))
    a=(file.read())
    label['text'] = a
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want the contents to be scrollable, why are you choosing to use a `Label`? The `Text` widget is designed to be a scrollable container for text.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do with a `Canvas` just to make a `Label` scrollable is an overkill in my opinion. You could use a `Text` widget instead and set its state to `disabled` to prevent the user from editing its content.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

# create text widget
text = tk.Text(root, background=root.cget('background'), relief='flat', height=10) 
# insert text 
content = "Long text to display\n" * 20
text.insert('1.0', content)
# disable text widget to prevent editing
text.configure(state='disabled')

# scrolling
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient='vertical', command=text.yview)
text.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

scroll.pack(side='right', fill='y')
text.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)

root.mainloop()
```